# Not able to build .NET Core Console Application in Linux

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rspec, .net-core, aruba

I have this spec file which is trying to run a script which will run the dotnet cli program:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Integration test', type: :aruba do
  let(:command) { run "dotnet-test" }

  it "test" do
    command.write("test\n")
    stop_all_commands
    expect(command.output).to end_with("success\n")
  end
end
```

`dotnet-test` script:

```
dotnet run --project ../SomeProject/src/SomeProject.Console/SomeProject.Console.csproj -- $1
```

But I get the error :

```
Failure/Error: expect(command.output).to end_with("success\n")
       expected "MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.\nSwitch: ../SomeProject/src/SomeProject.Console/SomeProject.Console.csproj\n\nThe build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.\n" to end with "success\n"
```

But if I run the script from that directory then program runs fine. Cannot figure out what could be the difference between the two. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: when you say "run the script from that directory" what exactly are you running and is that script ruby?

Comment: @lacostenycoder by that I mean when I just run the `dotnet-test` script from the terminal from the directory it runs fine but when the same script is executed from Aruba then it throws that error. Hope that explains it.

Comment: can you post the code you have in `dotnet-test` ?

Comment: `dotnet run --project ../SomeProject/src/SomeProject.Console/SomeProject.Console.csproj -- $1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the script you're trying to run relies on a relative path to execute correctly.  In that case you may need to `cd` within your spec.

See https://relishapp.com/cucumber/aruba/docs/filesystem/change-current-working-directory

Try to use the absolute path of the file instead of

```
../SomeProject/src/SomeProject.Console/SomeProject.Console.csproj
```

Can you put the full path, something like:

```
/Users/yourusername/pathtosomeproject/SomeProject/src/SomeProject.Console/SomeProject.Console.csproj
```

Obviously you'll need to replace `pathtosomeproject` to where it is actually located.

Comment: I tried changing it to : https://codeshare.io/a3Nd4m but now I get the error that `let` is not allowed within describe

Comment: I am no linux user but maybe I can change how the path to the project file is referenced?